# Path Finding used BFS in java

Tags: search, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

i have  this code , Breadth First search 
This code to represent graph , the search algorithm Breadth  search , I want you to question on it and it is

```
   void BFS(int s)
   {
       // Mark all the vertices as not visited(By default
       // set as false)
       boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];

       // Create a queue for BFS
       LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

       // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
       visited[s]=true;
       queue.add(s);

       while (queue.size() != 0)
       {
           // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
           s = queue.poll();
           System.out.print(s+" ");

           // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
           // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it
           // visited and enqueue it
           Iterator<Integer> i = adjacent_List[s].listIterator();
           while (i.hasNext())
           {
               int n = i.next();
               if (!visited[n])
               {
                   visited[n] = true;
                   queue.add(n);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I want to follow the path if you start from point 0 to look for point three, how can I modify the code to print the points it passed!
So you store tracks in Stack and print them

Comment: "how can I modify the code to print the points it passed ?" - 
 it alreadt does : `System.out.print(s+" ");` . For more detailed help post [mcve] with test data.

Answer (score 0):

Define a parent array where when you visit each node `n` in your loop, you set `par[n]=s`

in the end you should create a for-loop to get a chain of parents from three to 0

```
for (int i=3 ; i!=0 ; i=par[i])
    cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: This may be applicable when there are no loops, so each vertices has one parent.

Comment: @c0der BFS creates a tree so there's only one path between each 2 nodes. hence, only one parent for each vertice

Comment: BFS in this context is a search algorithm which can be used on any tree